# How to bind dropdown value in mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm unable to bind the dropdown value. Maybe I'm missing something in my code. Here I'm attaching my view code.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:0px;">                                                  
            @Html.DropDownList("ProofId", ViewBag.Idproofs as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control", id = "ProofType2", name = "ProofType2" })
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EvidenceData[1].ProofNumber, new { @class = "form-control", id = "IdNumber2", name = "IdNumber2" })
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EvidenceData[1].ProofImage, new { @class = "form-control", id = "ProofPic2", type = "file", name = "ProofPic2" })
            <a href="~/images/ProofPics/@Model.EvidenceData[1].ProofImage" download title="Download Image" style="text-decoration:underline;"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i> Download Image</a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And this is my controller code:

```
public ActionResult EditProfile(string country)
{
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        return new RedirectResult(Utility.Config("RedirectPath"));
    var idprooflist = AccountManager.LoadProoftypes(country ?? "United States");
    ViewBag.Idproofs = new SelectList(idprooflist, "ProofId", "ProofName");
    UserRegistration UserProfileData = ProviderManagerBLL.GetProviderDetails(Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"].ToString()));
    return View(UserProfileData);
}
```

Comment: what's your question is about? You can't fint it on POST? or what?

Comment: i am unable to bind the dropdown value

Answer (score 0):

The below should work for you:

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:0px;">                                                  
     @Html.DropDownList("ProofId", (SelectList)ViewBag.Idproofs, new { @class = "form-control", id = "ProofType2", name = "ProofType2" })
</div>
```

You are using a `ViewBag` to pass your values to the `View` and all you have to do is reference what you want from it. What you were doing before wouldn't work

Comment: HtmlHelper<UserRegistration> has no applicapble method named 'DropDownList' but apperas to have an extension method by that name. Extension method cannot be dyanmically dispatched

Comment: I tried this one also but not working @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.EvidenceData[1].ProofId, ViewBag.Idproofs as SelectList, "Select IdProof", new { @class = "form-control", id = "ProofType2", name = "ProofType2" })

Comment: i've updated my answer, i ommited one thing which i've added, `(SelectList)ViewBag.Idproofs` instead of just `ViewBag.Idproofs`

Comment: Are you getting same error? Why not pass it through the `model` you sending to your `View` then?

Comment: not a same error.value is not yet binded and i tried model like @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.EvidenceData[1].ProofId  it is also not working